# ¿ Cómo separar registros separadas con "/" usando split y listarlo con un each?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

espero de sus ayudas caso que tengo problemas al mostrar registros usando el split.

- Tengo varios registros en la base de datos separados con un **"/"** entonces lo quiero es mostrarlo en una tabla en el cual si encuentra una cadena separada por el / que muestre uno debajo del otro en la misma celda.
- ¿ Cómo podría solucionar ?

mi base de datos aqui..[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function mostrarDatos(valorBuscar, pagina, cantidad) {

  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "mantenimiento/logistica/proveedor/mostrar",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      buscar: valorBuscar,
      nropagina: pagina,
      cantidad: cantidad
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

      filas = "";
      var i = ((pagina - 1) * cantidad) + 1;
      $.each(response.proveedor, function(key, item) {
        filas += '<tr id=' + item.idProve + '>';
        filas += '<td style="width: 50px;">' + i++ + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 300px;">' + item.rzonProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 250px;">' + item.nomProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 100px;">' + item.rucProve + '</td>' +
          '<td >' + item.direProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 150px;">' + item.telfProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 150px;">' + item.contProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 200px;">' + item.celProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 250px;">' + item.emailProve + '</td>' +
          '<td style="width: 250px;"  align="center" ><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs item-info" data="' + item.idProve + '">ver familias</a></td>' +
          '<?php if ($permisosfuncion->opciones == 1): ?><td align="center" style="width: 150px;">' +
          '<?php if ($permisosfuncion->editar == 1): ?><a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs item-edit" data="' + item.idProve + '">Editar</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php endif;?>' +
          '<?php if ($permisosfuncion->eliminar == 1): ?><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs item-delete" data="' + item.idProve + '">Eliminar</a> <?php endif;?>' +
          '</td> <?php endif;?>' +
          '</tr>';
        $("#showdataProvee").html(filas);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno espero haber entendido lo que quieres hacer y para lograrlo podrías hacer algo como:

```
    //Tus campos separados por '/'
    var idProve  = "ID001/ID002/ID003";
    var telProve = "9660011/9660022/9660033";

    //Split de los campos (lista)
    idList  = idProve.split('/');
    telList = telProve.split('/');

    //Recorrer las listas para agregar el salto de página
    for (var indice in idList) {
        console.log(idList[indice] + "<br />");
    }

    for (var indice in telList) {
        console.log(telList[indice] + "<br />");
    }
```

En esta caso son 2 campos por decirlo asi. T'u tendrias que hacerlo por cada campo de tu BD que tenga listas separadas por '/'.
Espero te ayude!

Comment: Hola amigo me salio perfecto, pero cuando lista lo separa por una coma cómo lo elimino esa coma ?                                       example1@gmail.com , example2@gmail.com

Comment: Bueno en ese caso, teniendo por ejemplo: var text = "asasas@mail.com ,"; puedes hacer un replace: var clean = text.replace(/\,/g,''); Lo ultimo son comillas simples ''

Comment: me arroja un error como esta ** contacto.replace is not a function ** a que se debe ?

Comment: Me imagino que contacto es toda tu lista, y el replace se aplica a cada item, por ejemplo, si fuera para la lista de telefonos harías algo como: telList[indice].replace(/\,/g,''); es decir dentro del for.

Comment: Si justamente asi es, tengo otra consulta no se si podría ayudarme en esta, como podría  hacer un salto de linea después de cada cadena separada por el **/** asasas@mail.com , ejemplo@hotmail.com esos dos correos uno debajo del otro sin importar el tamaño de la cadena.

Comment: Si es para html es asi: telList[indice] + "<br />"

Answer (score 1):

En la documentacion oficial de PHP esta como se unsa el metoto Split, que es para separar una cadenar el ejmplo mas sencillo es dividir una `

```
 // Los delimitadores pueden ser barra, punto o guión
$fecha = "04/30/1973";
list($mes, $día, $año) = split('[/.-]', $fecha);
echo "Mes: $mes; Día: $día; Año: $año<br />\n";
?>`
```

Tomas la cadena en una variable y luego en list, pasas lo que queres recoger, y al metodo split le decir que delimitador va a reconocer para divivir la cadena, y luego pasas la cadena que has almacenado en la variable.
Tambien estas substr pero siento que es mas compleja

Answer (score 1):

Te dejare un ejemplo detallado

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//cadena o data de bd
var data = "direccion001/direccion002/direccion003/direccion004";
//elimnando el slash
var resultado=data.split("/");
//mostrando el resultado
for(i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
document.write("<li>"+resultado[i]+"</li>");
}
```

ya una vez separado del caracter (/) puedes hacer lo que desees con el resultado[Puedes ver el resultado Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/vau9udp5/5/)